# How to make UIScrollView scrollable even when contentSize is smaller than frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I am wondering how to make a UIScrollView always draggable even when the content size is smaller than the frame. A good example of this is a UITableView, which is a subclass of a UIScrollView, that responds to scroll gestures even when there is only 1 table view cell. How does a UITableView do this, and how can I apply it to a regular UIScrollView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After investigating, it seems like setting

```
scrollView.bounces = true
```

and

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

does the trick.